# Android WebView: browser out of date warning

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView in my app and I get a warning saying the internet browser is out of date. I can dismiss the popup but I was wondering if there is any way to avoid it
[image]

Comment: I think this may be an advertisement. Have you updated your WebView to the latest version from the Play Store ?

Comment: @Kunal Chawla yes I have everything updated as far as I know. It's like the website doesn't detect the browser correclty if you access from a webview...